# How to import contacts from galaxy s3 to nexus 5?

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-3, import, nexus-5

How do you import contacts from a Galaxy S3 to a Nexus 5?
They're both Android devices, so is it a simple process?
Do I need to save them to a SIM card?

Comment: If you use GMail and add contacts there, there is nothing you directly need to do outside of signing into that same account on the other android (and perhaps checking to sync contacts).

Comment: This might be useful: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/637/98

Comment: http://mashable.com/2013/08/20/sync-android-contacts/

Answer (score 1):

Several ways actually. The most simple way I found was to sync all your addresses to a Google Account. If you don't have one create one. On the S3:

1. From Settings Scroll down and choose Accounts and Sync.
2. Choose Add Account.
3. Choose Google.
4. Choose Existing to add an existing account.
5. Type in the email id of the account.
6. Fill in password and sign in.`

On the other device, simply sync to the account again. All your contacts will be pulled in.

Comment: Just tried it on my nexus 5, didn't work

Comment: Er, what didn't work- the sync from S3 to google happened?

Comment: yeah I ended up copying to sim. Then from sim

Comment: Well it's great- especially that your SIM could hold all data. But i'm surprised that sync did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would have been using the contacts' app integrated export/import functionality:

- on the "source device": open contacts, open menu, select "Export/Import", export to SDCard. This will export your entire contact list (including photos) to a `.vcf` file in the root of your sdcard.
- copy the resulting `*.vcf` file to the "target device"
- on the target device: open contacts, menu, export/import, import from SD. Chose the file.
- Done.

See also:

- [transferring contacts](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/24114/16575)
- [How can I transfer my all contacts from old HTC Wildfifre android 2.1 to LG Optimus Vu](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/52600/16575)
- [Moving from one droid to another](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/11240/16575)

Answer (score 0):

You use your gmail account to configure your contacts from one android phone to another.

1. Login into you google account from your Galaxy S3 Phone.
2. Sync your contacts with your gmail account.
3. Import contacts from your gmail account to your Nexus 5 by syncing your Nexus 5 with your gmail account.

Get access to all your contacts.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Dropbox on your S3 to save all your contacts in a cloud server as a VCF file (above), then sign in into the Dropbox account using your Nexus 5 and save the contacts in there. Google should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can use superbackup application from appstore. It stores almost evrything in seperate csv files, that way you can change your devices on fly, and still wont loose any data. Goodluck

Comment: Could you link the app?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idea.backup.smscontacts&hl=en